# proverb means Consider me as you want you will find me as you consider

Tags: proverbs

alot of companies expect effective performance. Nevertheless, it considers its employees as they are beginners (salary, ....).

He want to say:

> if you consider me as a Junior , you find me a Junior , That it means
>   : Don't expect from me to perfect tasks of Senior .
>
> And, if you consider me as an expert , you will find me an expert :

Is there a proverb means that ?

**UPDATE:**

the employer concentrate on experience .Indeed , he thought that "An expert is one who has worked for many years" . However ,It is not always so . you can find someone who has worked for a few years, but he is gifted .

It is not an issue of **Salary** , But It is a **psychological issue** that can negatively affect the performance of this gifted worker .

**He expects an appreciation befitting his skills**

Comment: There's a _term_ to cover this situation: _a self-fulfilling prophecy_. '_Mud sticks_' can have the meaning asked for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting  issue on job motivation and expectations.

I think you could  say that that your employer *will get what he deserves* by  keeping expectations lows failing to motivate his employees. If he treats you and pays you as a Junior, he is probably  likely to receive that standard of performance by you.

Comment: thank you so much Mr,Josh. I ve updated the question to explain more the meaning of expected proverb. Please, if you find this update useful . Telll me

Comment: I see, I think that in the end he will still 'get what he deserves' because he is trying to take advance of your skills, a very common problem in the job market, in the sense that either you will be demotivated or will leave the company.

Comment: Obviously. So right . thx a lot . A proverbs needed to be added to my profile at entreprise messagers

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure of how well an employer would take it, but the proverb '[You get what you pay for](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/you_get_what_you_pay_for)' conveys what I think it is you want to say:

> In commercial transactions, the quality of goods and services increases as the prices increase, i.e., the more one pays, the better the merchandise.

Comment: thank you so much Mr for your answe. I've updated the question to explain more the meaning of expected proverb. Please, if you find this update useful . Tell me

Answer (score 1):

Consider the idiomatic *get/have what's coming to one*.

> [**what's coming to one**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/what%27s+coming+to+one): what one deserves.